# Can't access features using QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString() if sink output is not temporary

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am writing a QGIS processing algorithm with several sink outputs. In the processAlgorithm function, I am trying to access one of the sink outputs using `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()` after features have been added to it.

If I do this when the output is set to temporary, this works perfectly and I am able to access the features in the sink.

If I try this when the output is set to a layer within a gpkg, there are no features in the new `QgsVectorLayer`.

I am assuming the reason for this with a written output is because the writing takes place on return? And if so, is there a way to get around this without having to create a memory layer before my sink insert step for accessibility later? If not, what could be causing this issue?